# sentiment analysis of a dataframe using if else statements

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I obtained the adjectives using this function:

```
def getAdjectives(text):

    blob=TextBlob(text)
    return [ word for (word,tag) in blob.tags if tag == "JJ"]

dataset['adjectives'] = dataset['text'].apply(getAdjectives)`
```

I obtained the dataframe from a json file using this code:

```
with open('reviews.json') as project_file:    
    data = json.load(project_file)
dataset=pd.json_normalize(data) 
print(dataset.head())
```

i have done the sentiment analysis for the dataframe using this code:

```
dataset[['polarity', 'subjectivity']] = dataset['text'].apply(lambda text: pd.Series(TextBlob(text).sentiment))
print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']])
```

this is the output:

```
                                          adjectives  polarity
0                                                 []  0.333333
1  [right, mad, full, full, iPad, iPad, bad, diff...  0.209881
2                             [stop, great, awesome]  0.633333
3                                          [awesome]  0.437143
4                        [max, high, high, Gorgeous]  0.398333
5                                     [decent, easy]  0.466667
6  [itâ€™s, bright, wonderful, amazing, full, few...  0.265146
7                                       [same, same]  0.000000
8         [old, little, Easy, daily, thatâ€™s, late]  0.161979
9                       [few, huge, storage.If, few]  0.084762
```

I have tried to filter the adjectives so as to determine those with positive, neutral and negative polarity in this code:

```
if dataset['polarity']> 0:
    print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']], "Positive")
        
elif dataset['polarity'] == 0:
    print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']], "Neutral")   
else: 
        print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']], "Negative")
```

I got the error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, but i have tried it using the "mask" method and the output is mixed up and incorrect

Comment: the code ```df=dataset

mask = df['polarity'].values > 0 
print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']], "Positive")
mask = df['polarity'].values == 0
print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']], "Neutral")
mask = df['polarity'].values < 0 
print(dataset[['adjectives', 'polarity']], "Negative")                                                                   ```

Comment: the output ```few  0.084762 Positive
   adjectives  polarity
0         NaN  0.333333
1       right  0.209881
1         mad  0.209881
1        full  0.209881
1        full  0.209881
1        iPad  0.209881
1        iPad  0.209881
1         bad  0.209881
1   different  0.209881
1   wonderful  0.209881
1        much  0.209881
1  affordable  0.209881
2        stop  0.633333
2       great  0.633333
2     awesome  0.633333
3     awesome  0.437143
4         max  0.398333
4        high  0.398333
4        high  0.398333 ``` the output is too long and incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `np.select` to determine the sentiment based on the polarity:

```
df['sentiment'] = np.select(
    [
        dataset['polarity'] > 0,
        dataset['polarity'] == 0
    ],
    [
        "Positive",
        "Neutral"
    ],
    default="Negative"
)
```

One-liner:

```
df['sentiment'] = np.select([dataset['polarity'] > 0, dataset['polarity'] == 0], ["Positive", "Neutral"], "Negative")
```